# Maven "package" vs Export as war in eclipse

Tags: java, maven

I was going through maven tutorial and found that package in goal will create war file for  web application ,but the same war file i can generate with export command of Eclipse.So my question is regarding the difference between both.

Comment: In the first case war would be assembled by Maven, in the second case - by Eclipse. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both the war files will be same in first case Maven will do the job of making war and deploying it to appropriate location so it made your life easy and in second case Eclipse will do the job for you and you need to deploy it manually.

Every time you want to deploy the application you have to export it and deploy it instead just config once run maven it will do all the necessary things automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maven manage the project, with it you can achive the Continuous Integration for example.

Eclipse is an IDE which let you code your project.

This is two different tools.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven for your project, I would suggest to use it completely. You can achieve a higher degree of automation for all the phases of the development. Along with the `package` goal, there are other goals as well like

```
validate,compile, test, package, integration-test, verify, install, deploy
```

Well eclipse also can do all these stuffs but I would say it as a tedious job as it needs a lot of manual attention. 
Also if the developers use different tools like netbeans, eclipse, etc, maven would be a helpful option